# Changing my PC's motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, integrated-graphics

I have a Asus A7N266 motherboard currently with a Athlon XP 1.8GHz processor that I assembled in 2002. The Video RAM for this is just 32 MB. I would like to upgrade my motherboard and retain the Processor. Is that advisable? If so, could you also suggest a good motherboard that has a better VGA capability?

Answer (score 3):

If you are unhappy with the video RAM why not buy a graphics card? It's way easier than swapping the motherboard.

And since your old computer is from 2002 I think it could be a problem for you to find a motherboard that would like your old RAM sticks and have the correct CPU socket. You'll probably have to buy a new motherboard, new RAM and a new CPU.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest the only place you'll be able to buy a motherboard that will work with that processor is going to be on eBay, and even then I would question how reliable to board would be given its age.

I've got a couple of motherboards with Athlon XP 2400s (2.0GHz iirc) fitted that are gathering dust in a box of bits somewhere.  They pretty much became too expensive to upgrade any individual part about 7 years ago.

You'll be better off buying some sort of [motherboard bundle](http://www.novatech.co.uk/novatech/bundles.html) from whoever your local supplier is, even the cheapest is likely to have a better processor and onboard graphics than a 2002 motherboard, with at least some current prospects for being upgradable without being extortionately expensive.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your processor has [Socket A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_A) pins. I have bad news - these died more than 5 years ago. You'll not find a motherbord with such socket today.